# MySQL is corrupted and not able to start mysql even after innodb_force_recovery=6

Tags: mysql

Here are Error logs from MySQL:

```
2023-09-25T23:38:12.380772Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.418767Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6192  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.421467Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6193  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.422620Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6194  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.423685Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6195  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.424557Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6196  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.425909Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6197  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.426901Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6198  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:16.030825Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.608005Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.613534Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 3568
2023-09-25T23:38:59.715343Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=100663296. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.761951Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-25T23:39:01.861228Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.849492Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.850185Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.954434Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.955369Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2023-09-26T05:50:57.065725Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2023-09-26T05:50:57.070263Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 3988
2023-09-26T05:50:57.150635Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=100663296. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-09-26T05:50:57.193995Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-26T05:50:59.560045Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-26T05:51:02.608838Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2023-09-26T05:51:02.614958Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2023-09-26T05:51:02.651234Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:81:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 4408
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-09-26T05:51:02Z UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1b01b26c880
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7c385fa68    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff7c29e9411    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff7c29e9153    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7c3843a7a    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7c3a9c7f9    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7c3976c20    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3975dd2    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c39752b4    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3974a9c    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3951b52    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3955644    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c395f07e    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c395f4e5    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ffa58166b4c    ucrtbase.dll!_recalloc()
7ffa59b94ed0    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffa5abfe40b    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I'm unable to start MySQL even after adding innodb_force_recovery=1 to 6. Please give any suggestions, everything is appreciated. I'm stuck with this issue for days now. If you need anything else, please let me know.

I have my database ibd files only, under data folder, please let me know if there is a way to recover them directly from idb files, although I tried by creating a new mysql instance, then creating database and tables and then tried to import the files into it, it failed though.

Comment: do you have a backup?

Comment: I suggest asking https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've searched through other answers on this site and dba.se, as well as bugs reported at bugs.mysql.com, and a few other sites. None of those posts shows a solution to repair a database corrupted this severely. I think the only solution is to restore from your most recent backup.

Comment: I would be inclined to copy all the database files and get them on to a laptop. Then introduce each set of files one table at a time - you may find that you have only lost one table.

Answer (score 1):

Critical MySQL corruption is beyond the scope of `innodb_force_recovery`. If you have `.ibd` files, you can attempt to import them into a fresh MySQL instance using transportable tablespaces.

```sql
-- On the new MySQL instance
ALTER TABLE your_database.your_table DISCARD TABLESPACE;
-- Copy your .ibd file to the appropriate directory in the new instance
ALTER TABLE your_database.your_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Note: This process assumes that table metadata (.frm files) is available and that the MySQL versions are compatible. If the import still fails, you may need to resort to specialized recovery tools or services.

Comment: Can you please suggest any recovery tool?

Comment: I can suggest you don't host your own database & email servers. Rent one from a place like Digital Ocean - Managed Databases. Outsource this type of headache to a Secure Data Center and the worst you can do from then on is intentionally DROP or TRUNCATE a table, but never really catastrophically corrupt it. You will always have daily & instant backup available to save your data ready to go.

Comment: As for the to answer your comment, search Google for MySQL InnoDB Recovery Tool.